# Corda fails to startup if hibernate_sequence is already created in Postgres

Tags: spring, corda

My Spring and Corda nodes share the same Posgres database. When I start first Corda nodes and then Spring everything goes smoothly. But if I start everything together like 'docker-compose up' I see following exception. It seems that Corda doesn't like if Spring creates hibernate_sequence first.

I see this problem with Corda 4.0 but with Corda 3.3 everything worked fine.

Is there any way to avoid this not-expected behaviour?

```
> ! ATTENTION: This node is running in development mode!  This is not safe for production deployment.
[ERROR] 14:50:53+0000 [main] liquibase.severe - master.changelog.json: migration/common.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-1.3::R3.Corda: Change Set migration/common.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-1.3::R3.Corda failed.  Error: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE SEQUENCE public.hibernate_sequence MINVALUE 1]
[ERROR] 14:50:53+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Could not create the DataSource: Migration failed for change set migration/common.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-1.3::R3.Corda:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE SEQUENCE public.hibernate_sequence MINVALUE 1]: Could not create the DataSource: Migration failed for change set migration/common.changelog-init.xml::1511451595465-1.3::R3.Corda:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE SEQUENCE public.hibernate_sequence MINVALUE 1] [errorCode=euq4co, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/5.0-SNAPSHOT/euq4co]
```

Comment: I've not upgraded to Corda4 yet. so I'm not sure why the migration-related activities are happening at the time of node startup. anyway, the thing is if you look into `migration/common.changelog-init.xml` you'll find it creates `hibernate_sequence` with something like `create sequence hibernate_sequence start 1 increment 1;`. Since your spring has already created the `hibernate_sequence` possibly because you've `@GeneratedValue` somewhere in your entity. when corda starts it cannot again create the `hibernate_sequence` and right now it doesn't seem to recover from it.

Comment: so do what you are doing already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed sequenceExists precondition solved the issue. The fix is pushed to Corda master in 57d0040.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug documented here: https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-2393.

Comment: It sounds really close but slightly different. 2393's problem if I understand correctly is that in some cases Hibernate fails to create the sequence so there is no sequence at all. While in my case sequence is already there when Corda's Hibernate tries to create it. So it fails during this initial db setup step. So Corda startup fails.

Comment: I think the solution is to add `<sequenceExists>` precondition to `common.changelog-init.xml` somewhere between lines 12 and 13. Because `hibernate_sequence` is very widely used and it's better not to fail if there is one already. I can prepare PR if you think it's correct approach.